# Making a Python Quiz

Tags: python

I'm doing a project that is a quiz filling the gaps and I'm having an error and I can not identify. After I fail to respond to a gap, the quiz does not show the phrase that should appear and an error appears. Can someone help me? I have tried some things and nothing happens, always when an attempt to hit is wrong it shows the error instead of showing the amount of attempts that the player still has or that he has lost.
Follow the code:
PS: The code is in PT_BR

```
# coding=utf-8
# Meu quiz

print ("Escolha o nível de dificuldade para o seu jogo. Digite F para fácil, M para médio, ou D para difícil.")


# Lista do total de tentativas já feitas
count_list = []

perguntas = [
    "Digite a palavra que corresponde ao espaço 0: ",
    "Digite a palavra que corresponde ao espaço 1: ",
    "Digite a palavra que corresponde ao espaço 2: ",
    "Digite a palavra que corresponde ao espaço 3: "
]


def verificacao(frase, gabarito, tentativas):
    # Verificação das palavras do jogo com contabilização
    print
    print (frase)
    print

    index = 0

    while len(count_list) < tentativas and index < (tentativas + 1):
        pergunta = input(perguntas[index]).lower()

        if index == tentativas and pergunta == gabarito[index]:
          print
          print ("Parabéns! Você ganhou!")
          break

        if pergunta == gabarito[index]:
            print
            print ("Você acertou!")
            print
            frase = frase.replace(str(index), gabarito[index])
            print (frase)
            index += 1
            print

        else:
            count_list.append(1)
            print
            print ("Você errou. Você tem mais") + str(
                tentativas - len(count_list)) + "tentativa(s)."
            print

            if len(count_list) == tentativas:
                print ("Você perdeu.")
                break    


# Variáveis do jogo
frase_facil = "Água __0__, pedra __1__, tanto __2__ até que __3__."
frase_medio = "De __0__, poeta e __1__, todo __2__ tem um __3__."
frase_dificil = "Um __0__, de exemplos __1__ mais que uma __2__ de __3__."

frases = [frase_facil, frase_medio, frase_dificil]

gabarito_facil = ['mole', 'dura', 'bate', 'fura']
gabarito_medio = ['medico', 'louco', 'mundo', 'pouco']
gabarito_dificil = ['grama', 'vale', 'tonelada', 'conselhos']

gabaritos = [gabarito_facil, gabarito_medio, gabarito_dificil]


def attempts():
    # Verifica se a tentativas informada é válida, e retorna apenas se o valor for válido
    while True:
        try:
            tentativas = int(
                input("Quantas tentativas que você quer ter? "))
            return tentativas
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Você precisa digitar um número. Tente outra vez.")
            continue


while True:
    # Pega o input do usuário sobre o nível de dificuldade e número de tentativas desejada, para iniciar o quiz correto com a dificuldade correta.
    nivel_dificuldade = input("Nível de dificuldade: ")
    tentativas = attempts()

    if nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "f" or nivel_dificuldade.lower(
    ) == "facil" or nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "fácil":
        verificacao(frase_facil, gabarito_facil, tentativas)
        break
    elif nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "m" or nivel_dificuldade.lower(
    ) == "medio" or nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "médio":
        verificacao(frase_medio, gabarito_medio, tentativas)
        break
    elif nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "d" or nivel_dificuldade.lower(
    ) == "dificil" or nivel_dificuldade.lower() == "difícil":
        verificacao(frase_dificil, gabarito_dificil, tentativas)
        break
    print ("Para escolher a dificuldade do seu quiz, você precisa apertar F, M ou D. Tente novamente.")
```

Comment: it might be easier to follow your logic if you translate comments/strings/variable names to english

Comment: When asking a question about code that produces an error/exception, please include the complete Traceback in the question: copy the Traceback and paste it into the question formatted as code. also, if user input is required, include the *input(s)* that produce the error.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: I agree with wwii, and would also like to ask for details in what you've already tried.

Comment: this is the error that is appearing after an attempt to hit the quiz is wrong https://imgur.com/a/1vKfsWH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

The problem is with line 46 of the code you've posted, in the `else` block in the first `while` loop. This part:

```
print ("Você errou. Você tem mais") + str(
    tentativas - len(count_list)) + "tentativa(s)."
```

Since you close the parentheses around `"Você errou. Você tem mais"`, you are printing just that string. Then you attempt to concatenate the result of `print` with the next string (`str(tentativas - len(count_list))`), so you get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

since `print` does not return anything (i.e. `None`).

**The Solution**

To Fix this simply place that first closing parenthesis at the end of the line so that all string concatenation is done within the parentheses and the whole result is printed.

Here's what that looks like:

```
print ("Você errou. Você tem mais" + str(
      tentativas - len(count_list)) + "tentativa(s).")
```